# Windows Service changing its own DLL files

Tags: c#, .net, dll, windows-services, log4net

I am experiencing an awkward issue with a windows service I have developed. Suddenly the service started to crash when starting and, after many days of tough research I have found this: some dlls inside the directory in the production server were of a different size than the ones inside the development server. Just for you to know, the process is this:

- I develop the service using Visual Studio 2013 in a local Windows 7 machine.
- I then compile the service and copy the files generated in the bin/Debug directory into the production server, an Amazon EC2 Machine. (p.s.: I tried to install the service using the files inside the bin/Release directory but this were of no effect)

For many weeks, while the windows service worked properly, the files in the production server and those in the development machine were exactly the same, except for some minor differences in the service's .config file.  When the problem first appeared I started to see this one difference: many DLL files in the production machine suddenly became swollen, like 3 or 4 times its original size in megabytes.

Just for you to know, the service uses log4net library for logging procedures.

Any tip?

Comment: Well, don't hesitate to unplug that machine asap.  Alert IT staff about it, or whomever is responsible for keeping the company running.

Answer (score 1):

You should install a virus/malware scanner. When nobody changes anything and the dll are changing, your environments is probably compromised.

Comment: It is worthy to notice that the same service runs correctly in the development machine. The problem of "swollen dlls" does not happen in the dev machine.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The issue was due to a synchronization service between the two server machines. Once I disabled synchronization for the windows service folder, the problem disapeared.